# im4java: is possible create a final image using others different images?

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

My project give me 3 images:

1. track.jpg (background full size)
2. pilote.jpg (40% of full size, position left)
3. car.jpg (40% of full size, position right)

Basically I need to get these 3 images resize and reposition it, and finally create a new image.

My code so far:

`

```
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("E:/jpeg/background.jpg");
op.resize(800,600);
op.addImage("E:/jpeg/pilote.jpg");
op.addImage("E:/jpeg/car.jpg");

op.compress("JPEG");
op.addImage("E:/thumraca.jpg");
cmd.run(op);
```

`

How can I position my two images left and right?